# Springboot security config not redirecting to successUrl

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I dont seem to understand what is wrong with my code. I'm trying to login using Springboot security, everything seems correct and I can see my username and password on console. Can anyone tell me what i'm getting wrong?

Here's my SecSecurityConfig class

```
     package com.scanapp.config;
     import com.scanapp.repositories.RoleRepository;
     import com.scanapp.services.UserDetailsService;
     import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
     import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
     import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
     import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
     import 
     org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
     import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

     @Configuration
     @EnableWebSecurity
     public class SecSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


     @Autowired
     private RoleRepository roleRepository;




    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myuserdet")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    protected void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("I'm here");
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        System.out.println("got here");
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new 
       DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
      {

        return new CustomPassword();
       }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/resources**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
                    .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").successForwardUrl("/index").defaultSuccessUrl("/index",true).failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .csrf().disable();
        System.out.println("got here too");
        }

    }
```

UserServiceDetails.java

```
package com.scanapp.services;

import com.drew.metadata.StringValue;
import com.scanapp.config.MyUserPrincipal;
import com.scanapp.config.SecSecurityConfig;
import com.scanapp.models.User;
import com.scanapp.repositories.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import java.util.Objects;


@Qualifier("myuserdet")
@Service
public class UserDetailsService implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {


        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(username);

        if (Objects.nonNull(user)) {
            MyUserPrincipal principal = new MyUserPrincipal(user);
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(principal));
            System.out.println("User Found");
            System.out.println(principal.getPassword());
            System.out.println(principal.getUsername());
            return principal;
        }else {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("User Not found");
        }

    }
}
```

MyUserPrincipal.java

```
package com.scanapp.config;

import com.scanapp.models.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Collection;

public class MyUserPrincipal implements UserDetails {



        private User user;

        public MyUserPrincipal(User user) {
            this.user = user;
        }


    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

            return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword()
    {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername()
    {
        return user.getEmail();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

CustomPassword.java

```
package com.scanapp.config;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

public class CustomPassword extends BCryptPasswordEncoder {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
        return super.encode(rawPassword);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
        System.out.println("paasword etered {}" + rawPassword);
        return super.matches(rawPassword, encodedPassword);
    }
}
```

Comment: still worth to remove although, because it nut used anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove this block from the configuration. In theory Spring creates all of these beans behind the scenes (picking up your passwordEncoder and UserDetailsService automatically).

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myuserdet")
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
protected void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("I'm here");
    auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
    System.out.println("got here");
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new 
   DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authProvider;
}
```

If it doesn't work try to rename your UserDetailsService (although that's a long shot).

Comment: It wont work. What do you mean by "rename" UserDetailsService?

Comment: Rename the class to something else. Have you actually tried removing those beans?

Comment: Okay, i renamed but its still same thing. If i remove the bean, am I supposed to  configure something else? I'm really new to spring

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of noise in your code.

1.You defined CustomPassword which just extends BCryptPasswordEncoder. I suggest to return

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

2. You defined another User model which does nothing and has null list of granted authorities. It is odd, because it should fail if the list of authorities is null. Please return import

```
org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;

//..
return new User(userName, encodedPassword, Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER")
```

3.It is better to use another names for your beans, not the spring ones. please rename UserDetailsService to CustomUserDetailsService and don't use qualifiers in your configuration.

4.Please make sure that when you save the passwords in your database, they are hashed with BCryptPasswordEncoder.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Another idea:
Based on the docs this method shouldn't return null:

```
@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

        return null;
}
```

return `AuthorityUtils.NO_AUTHORITIES;` instead.

In theory it could raise a `NullpointerException` during the authentication AFTER your UserDetailsService created the principal. And if there is a general `catch (Exception e)` somewhere there then it will be simply embedded into an `AuthenticationException`.

--- Edit

OUCH!

You should also change the return value to `true` in the last four method in the `MyUserPrincipal` class:

```
@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}
```

Your princapal was always disabled and expired and all. Of course it was not allowed to log in ! :)

Comment: Sadly even after returning AuthorityUtils.NO_AUTHORITIES, I still can't login